# Evaluate angular js variables using protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, jasmine, protractor

I have a canvas pie chart that I'd like to test using protractor.
the html element looks like:

```
<canvas id ="my_pie" data-values="ctl.gfx.values" data-categories="ctl.gfx.categories"...
```

In my protractor code I am able to evaluate each attribute data-values and data-categories as follow:

```
...
 var canvas = element(by.css("canvas#my_pie"));
...
 canvas.evaluate("ctl.gfx.categories").then(function(c){
        console.log(c);            
    });
 canvas.evaluate("ctl.gfx.values").then(function(l){
        console.log(v);
    });
```

everything works fine and data is logged out on the console, but if I try to return the arrays themselves, they get returned as empty arrays, I understand this has something to do with promises as that's what the protractor evaluate function stands for but I cannot figure this out because I am totally new to JS, Jasmine and Protractor.

basically the expected logic should be like:

```
function getMyData(){
   var myCategories = [];
   var myValues = [];

   canvas.evaluate("ctl.gfx.categories").then(function(c){
        myCategories = c;            
    });

   canvas.evaluate("ctl.gfx.values").then(function(v){
        myValues = v;
    });

    // do something with both arrays, concat and return a result
   //final statement would be a return statement.
}
```

what I would like to do is return the result of those arrays after some processing but to me it seems like the return statement runs always first, hence the empty result.

Answer (score 0):

You not understand the Async programming/Promise in Protractor, please learn and make you clear the key points this link what to express: http://www.protractortest.org/#/control-flow#promises-and-the-control-flow

Then look into this link I answer other question to explain what happen when run Protracotr script: [promise chaining vs promise.all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47401898/promise-chaining-vs-promise-all/47403993#47403993)

Then look below, I explained why you always get a empty array in code comment

```
function getMyData(){
   var myCategories = [];
   var myValues = [];

   canvas.evaluate("ctl.gfx.categories").then(function(c){
        myCategories = c;            
    });

   canvas.evaluate("ctl.gfx.values").then(function(v){
        myValues = v;
    });

   // Assume we concat the two array and return the new array as below code shows
   var ret = myCategories.concat(myValues);
   return ret;

   // When JavaScript engine explain and execute below code line: 
   // var ret = myCategories.concat(myValues);

   // the above two canvas.evaluate() have not resoved, because they are 
   // executed async not sync.
   // so the myCategories and myValues have not assigned new value, they are 
   // still empty array at this time point, so always return empty array
}
```

To resolve your problem, try below code example:

```
function getMyData(){

    return Promise.all([
        canvas.evaluate("ctl.gfx.categories"),
        canvas.evaluate("ctl.gfx.values")
    ]).then(function(data){
        let myCategories = data[0];
        let myValues = data[1];
        return myCategories.concat(myValues);
    });
}


getMyData().then(function(myData){
    console.log(myData);
    // put your code to consume myData at here
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.